# error to send Authorization headers in swift 3 don't work, (the server dont' receive the Authorization headers )

Tags: swift, web-services, token

I have the problem, my server doesn't receive the header Authorization,
I try with this code but doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
let token: String? = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.79HJPR04IjHBwLzpeUnjJel0UAYSG0rtqPvOPca7Uds"

guard let name = token, !name.isEmpty else { return }

let url = URL(string: "http://dev.viupruebas.com.mx/webservice/test/getvehiculos")
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("Bearer \(name)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: If your backend is PHP you might have problems with that header name. Test with any other name to check if it works

Comment: ok, which header name will be? you can give me a example the header name? please

Comment: in postman works correctly

Comment: Firstly, I'll run charles and check whether my headers are being passed in the request... Then I'll start investigating the iOS App.

Comment: ok, thank you, in postman works correctly but in my code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i resolve my problem read the nex line:

> let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response,
>   error in

my finaly code is:

```
let token: String? = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MjE4MjY2MTgsImV4cCI6MTUyNDQxODYxOCwiZGidXN1YXJpbyI6IjEiLCJpcCI6IjE4Ny4xNTUuOTIuMjEzIn19.pu6_1LmfxliXke_WMY82hEKy0Dsn1fk-feaTKnfGpbo"

              guard let name = token, !name.isEmpty else { return }
        //url
        let url = URL(string: "http:/webservice")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.addValue("\(name)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
```